# Client won't talk to ATL Service

Tags: c++, com, service, atl

I'm having a problem with an ATL Service that exports a COM object. It works running as a local service, but when running as a Windows Service, I can't connect. The service starts correctly and runs, but my client (code below) always fails with the error "Failed to start service".

So we're looking at the same thing, I've put together a minimal project that will reproduce this issue on my PC.

File->New Project
  Visual C++ -> ATL "ATL Project"
  Name: "MyService"
Under Application Settings, select "Service (EXE)"

Go to "Class View"
Right click on "MyService" and Add -> Class
  select: "ATL Simple Object"
  Short Name: "MyObject"

Go to "Solution View"
Right-click "Solution 'MyService'" and Add -> "New Project" 
This will be a "Visual C++" -> "Win32" "Win32 Console Applicaion"
  Name: "MyClient"
Check the "Add common header files for ATL" box

In client.cpp, use this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "../MyService/Debug/MyService.tlb"

#include <iostream>

using namespace MyServiceLib;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize( NULL );

    try
    {
        IMyObjectPtr spQueue( __uuidof( MyObject ) );
    }
    catch( const _com_error& Err )
    {
        std::wcout << L"Error: " << Err.ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        std::wcout << L"Unexpected Error" << std::endl;
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
    std::wcout << L"Finished" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Open the "Project Dependencies"
  Project "MyClient" depends on "MyService"

Build the solution.

From the command prompt, run the following commands: 
MyService /Service
net start MyService
client

Answer (score 1):

Do you select option "Add common header files for: ATL" in app MyClient ?
This one work fine in my test.

Put service running at your user account (default is system account) for access at debugging IDE.

Good lock.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make additional registry entries under progid.
I do not see where you are calling 'CoInitializeSecurity'

Microsoft supplies an example at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ts2dxc8.aspx

--

Michael

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the ATL registry templates (Visual Studio 2008/2010). The .rgs file for the component is missing an AppID value, as described in [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jigarme/archive/2008/05/08/cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-for-visual-studio-2008-based-atl-service.aspx)

Add the following line above the *'TypeLib...'* line in MyObject.rgs

```
val AppID = s '%APPID%'
```